# C# 3.5 : How do I get the name of the parent class from a UserControl?

Tags: c#

C# 3.5 : How do I get the name of the parent class dynamically from within a UserControl?

For example,

If **TestPage.aspx** contains UserControl **ucTestUc**,

I need to know that the parent class is TestPage.

I tried: from within **ucTestUc**,

**this.Parent.NamingContainer** is  ASP.testpage_aspx .

Which is close, but no cigar.

I could get rid of the prefix and postfix, but I have no way of restoring the capitalization.

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string typeName = this.Page.GetType().Name;

string baseTypeName = this.Page.GetType().BaseType.Name;

string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath);
```

Comment: Or `if (Page.GetType() is TestPage) { ... }`

Comment: @Lill: You asked for the parent *class*, and `this.Page.GetType().BaseType.Name` will give you that with the correct capitalisation.

Comment: Best answer is 
this.Page.GetType().BaseType.Name 
as it give me exactly what I need: TestPage.
2nd best is Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath) as it give me 
TestPage.aspx and I could get rid of the .aspx.  Thanks Luke!